# In r, how can I create a list from a matrix with NAs stripped?

Tags: list, r

I have a character matrix with differing numbers of NA in different rows. I would like to create a structure that has the same number of rows, with all the NAs removed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a simple apply :

```
x <- matrix(1:10,ncol=2)
x[c(4,7,8)] <- NA

apply(x,1,na.exclude)
```

---

edit : if all rows have exactly the same amount of NA's, then this will return a matrix. For conversion of this matrix to a list, see : [How to convert a matrix to a list of column-vectors in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819804/how-to-construct-a-list-from-the-columns-or-rows-of-a-matrix) .