# Long format into list, listFromLong results in: argument 1 is not a vector

Tags: r

I have been trying to run the [`MSCMT::listFromLong`](https://rdrr.io/cran/MSCMT/src/R/listFromLong.r) command to transform a data frame from long format to list. I am sure that my data is in long format, however whenever I run the code I run into the following error

```
Error in order(rownames(res[[i]])) : argument 1 is not a vector
```

After looking at the `listFromLong`'s source code I realized that the error must be somewhere along the lines between ** ** in this code:

```
> listFromLong <- function(foo, unit.variable, time.variable, 
>                          unit.names.variable=NULL,exclude.columns=NULL) {  
> if(!is.data.frame(foo)) stop("foo must be a data.frame")
> 
>   # main helper function   DFtoList <-
> function(input,rowcol,colcol,colnamecol=NULL,exclude=NULL) {
>     stopifnot(length(dim(input))==2)
>     datcols    <- setdiff(seq_len(ncol(input)), 
>                           c(rowcol,colcol,colnamecol,exclude))
>     *res        <- vector("list",length(datcols))*
>     names(res) <- if (!is.null(colnames(input))) colnames(input)[datcols] else 
>                                                  as.character(datcols)
>     if (!is.null(colnamecol)) {
>       c2n        <- na.omit(unique(input[,colnamecol]))
>       names(c2n) <- na.omit(unique(input[,colcol]))
>     }  
>     for (i in seq_along(res)) {
>       idx  <- !is.na(input[,datcols[i]])
>       rown <- unique(input[idx,rowcol])
>       coln <- unique(input[idx,colcol])
>       res[[i]] <- matrix(NA,nrow=length(rown),ncol=length(coln))
>       rownames(res[[i]]) <- rown
>       colnames(res[[i]]) <- coln
>       for (j in which(idx)) 
>         res[[i]][as.character(input[j,rowcol]),as.character(input[j,colcol])]
> <- 
>           input[j,datcols[i]]
>       **if (!is.null(colnamecol)) colnames(res[[i]]) <- c2n[as.character(coln)]**
> **      res[[i]] <- res[[i]][order(rownames(res[[i]])),,drop=FALSE]**
>     }
>     res   }
```

I can't pinpoint the exact source of the error as, to my understanding, the data is ready to be processed by this code. I would appreciate it if someone could tell me how to locate "Argument 1", or give me an explanation as to why it was not converted to a vector in the line between ** **.

My data was imported from Stata using

```
data <- readstata13::read.dta13("path/data.dta")
```

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Also show expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Please don't *mark up* code with anything except comments symbols: it makes it just a little more inconvenient to test your code. Please [edit] your question and remove the leading `>` and `**` highlights. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where the error occurs, but as far as I see the function basically splits the data along the index "regionname" into matrices using "year" as row names. After that, it transposes things so that there is a list of matrices of the original columns with now countries in the columns.

We could do the same very simple using an `array`, transposing it accordingly using `aperm`, and finally convert into a list using `split.along.dim()` from [*@flodel's* answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20207820/6574038).  *Example:*

```
data(basque, package="Synth")
B <- split.along.dim(aperm(simplify2array(by(basque, basque$regionname, function(x) {
  `rownames<-`(as.matrix(x[,!names(x) %in% c("regionno", "regionname", "year")]),
               x[,"year"])})), c(1, 3, 2)), 3)
```

With your original data you would just replace the data and column names.

Now let's check if the result is equal to that of `MSCMT::listFromLong`.

```
Basque <- MSCMT::listFromLong(basque, unit.variable="regionno", 
                              time.variable="year", 
                              unit.names.variable="regionname")
```

Weirdly, `MSCMT::listFromLong` deletes all rows of the list elements with `NA`s, but let's do it...

```
B <- lapply(B, function(x) x[apply(x, 1, function(x) !all(is.na(x))), ])
```

Columns of our *B* are sorted alphabetically, we do that with *Basque*.

```
Basque <- lapply(Basque, function(x) x[, order(colnames(x))])
```

Now check,

```
all.equal(Basque, B)
# [1] TRUE
```

et voilà!

---

*Function of [*@flodel*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20207820/6574038), that transforms an array into a list:*

```
split.along.dim <- function(a, n) {
  setNames(lapply(split(a, arrayInd(seq_along(a), dim(a))[, n]),
                  array, dim = dim(a)[-n], dimnames(a)[-n]),
           dimnames(a)[[n]])
}
```