# Get all possible combinations by row in matrix

Tags: r, matrix, combinations, combn

I have an `m` x `n` matrix that looks like this:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

What is the fastest way to get all possible combinations by row? In this case, that would be `c(1,4), c(1,5), c(1,6), c(2,4), c(2,5) ... c(3,5), c(3,6)`

How do I solve this using a vectorized approach? In general an `m` x `n` matrix would have `n^m` such combinations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `expand.grid` function to get all combinations of the elements in each row, building a list of rows using `split` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6819804/3093387) and passing each element of that list to `expand.grid` with the `do.call` function:

```
(m <- rbind(1:3, 4:6))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    2    3
# [2,]    4    5    6
do.call(expand.grid, split(m, rep(1:nrow(m), ncol(m))))
#   1 2
# 1 1 4
# 2 2 4
# 3 3 4
# 4 1 5
# 5 2 5
# 6 3 5
# 7 1 6
# 8 2 6
# 9 3 6
```

Here's an example with a 3 x 2 matrix instead of a 2 x 3 matrix:

```
(m <- matrix(1:6, nrow=3))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    4
# [2,]    2    5
# [3,]    3    6
do.call(expand.grid, split(m, rep(1:nrow(m), ncol(m))))
#   1 2 3
# 1 1 2 3
# 2 4 2 3
# 3 1 5 3
# 4 4 5 3
# 5 1 2 6
# 6 4 2 6
# 7 1 5 6
# 8 4 5 6
```

Comment: `expand.grid(split(m, row(m)))` might be simpler