# How to pass arguments to function called from mapply directly OR how to treat vector as argument to function not to mapply

Tags: r, mapply

Suppose I have following function:

```
my.fun1 <- function(a,b,c){
  a * c + b
}
```

If I want to call it several times with multiple arguments I can do:

```
> my.fun1(1, 1, c(1:3))
[1] 2 3 4
> my.fun1(2, 2, c(1:3))
[1] 4 6 8
> my.fun1(3, 3, c(1:3))
[1]  6  9 12
```

But if I use `mapply` I get this:

```
> mapply(my.fun1, c(1:3), c(1:3), c(1:3))
[1]  2  6 12
```

Instead of desired:

```
[[1]]
[1] 2 3 4

[[2]]
[1] 4 6 8

[[3]]
[1]  6  9 12
```

IMHO the problem is that `mapply` basically translates the function call to:

```
> my.fun1(1, 1, 1)
[1] 2
> 
> my.fun1(2, 2, 2)
[1] 6
> 
> my.fun1(3, 3, 3)
[1] 12
```

How can I pass last argument of `mapply` directly to `my.fun1` without being treat as argument to `mapply` but rather to `my.func1`?

PS: I've been playing with anonymous functions inside `maplpy` call. The closest is get (based on suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819804/how-to-convert-a-matrix-to-a-list-of-column-vectors-in-r)):

```
> x <- mapply(function(x, y){my.fun1(x, y, c(1:3))}, c(1:3), c(1:3))
> split(x, rep(1:ncol(x), each = nrow(x)))
$`1`
[1] 2 3 4

$`2`
[1] 4 6 8

$`3`
[1]  6  9 12
```

But I guess this is ugly approach and there must be better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the last input in `my.fun1` is the same `vector`, we place that in a `list` and pass it as argument for `Map` or `mapply`.

```
Map(my.fun1, 1:3, 1:3, list(1:3))
```

Or as @baptiste mentioned, the constants can be passed with `MoreArgs`

```
Map(my.fun1, 1:3, 1:3, MoreArgs = list(c=1:3))
```

When we are using `mapply`, it is better to have `SIMPLIFY=FALSE` to avoid coercing the `list` to `matrix` (if the lengths of the `list` elements are the same.

```
mapply(my.fun1, 1:3, 1:3, list(1:3), SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

Comment: i would usually pass constants as `MoreArgs=list(c=1:3)`

Comment: @thank you. I see that in both cases (`Map` and `mapply`) casting vector to list is used. Why this work this way, is list passed somehow differently to function than vector or what is the trick?

Comment: @WakanTanka  `Map` is a convenient function for `mapply`.  If you check the `Map` function, it is just `mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE)`.  Regarding the `list` working differently, it is just that there is only a single element in that `list`.  So,it got recycled for each of the corresponding elements of the vectors